# Lebesgue Outer measure equivalence

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $E\subset \mathbb {R}^n$ a measurable set and $A\subset E$.

Prove $$|E\setminus A|_e=\inf \{|E\setminus F|: F\subset A, F \text{ closed} \}$$

Here $|\cdot|$ is the Lebesgue's measure and $|\cdot|_e$ is the exterior measure

$\leq$ is obvious but for $\geq$ I'm lost, any idea? Thanks!

Comment: What is $|B|_e$ ? It's not standard notation.

Comment: @user254665 the Lebesgue's outer measure

Comment: What have you tried for $\geq$? If you write out the definition of the LHS you’re half way there.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is equivalent of saying $λ_*(E)+λ^*(Ε\setminus A)=λ(Ε)$ (where $λ_*$ denotes the inner measure and $λ^*$ denotes the outer measure.I will show proove this then.

First off, there exists a $B$ measurable such that $E\setminus A \subset B$ and $λ_*(E\setminus A)=λ(Β)$ therefore $λ(E\setminus B)\leq λ*(Α)$.

But $λ(E\setminus B)=λ(Ε)-λ(Β)=λ(Ε)-λ^*(Ε\setminus A)$ and $λ_*(A)\geq λ(Ε)-λ^*(Ε\setminus A) $ therefore $μ_*(Α)+μ^*(Ε\setminus A)\geq λ(Ε)$

The other direction is, as you say , obvious.